Post request using fetch fails to be sent after using spring security
I am working on a small project where I used spring security. Before I used spring security, I was sending a post request using fetch. As soon as I implemented spring security, the requests were blocked. I am new to Spring Security so I am lost as to what I should do.
This is the fetch request:
<script>
        document.getElementById('ratingSubmit').addEventListener('click', () => {
            let stars = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="star-rating"]');
            let selectedValue = null;

            for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
                if (stars[i].checked) {
                    selectedValue = stars[i].value;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (selectedValue !== null) {
                const url = window.location.search;
                const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(url);
                if (urlParams.has('id')) {
                    const id = urlParams.get('id');
                    console.log(selectedValue);
                    console.log(id);
                    fetch("/movie/rate", {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-type' : 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({movie_id : id, rating : selectedValue})
                    }).then((resp) => {
                        return resp.text();
                    }).then((resp) => {
                        let message = 'Failed to submit';
                        if (resp === 'Success')
                            message = `Successfully submitted a rating of ${selectedValue} stars`;
                        alert(message)
                    })
                }
            } else {
                alert("No stars were selected");
            }
        });
    </script>

The controller responsible for the rating is this one
package javaproj.movieRental.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import javaproj.movieRental.DTO.RatingRequest;
import javaproj.movieRental.entities.Rating;
import javaproj.movieRental.entities.User;
import javaproj.movieRental.repositories.MovieRepository;
import javaproj.movieRental.repositories.RatingRepository;
import javaproj.movieRental.repositories.UserRepository;
import javaproj.movieRental.security.CustomUserDetails;
import javaproj.movieRental.services.RatingServicesImp;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movie/rate")
public class RatingController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private RatingRepository ratingRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @PostMapping(consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveRating(@RequestBody RatingRequest rr, Authentication authentication) {
        CustomUserDetails userDetails = (CustomUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
        User user = userDetails.getUser();
        
        Long user_id = user.getId();
        Long movie_id = rr.getMovie_id();
        int rating = rr.getRating();
        
        System.out.println("User id: " + user_id + "\nMovie id: " + movie_id + "\nRating: " + rating );
        Rating userRating = ratingRepository.getByUserIdAndMovieId(user_id, movie_id);
        if (userRating != null) {
            userRating.setRating(rating);
            ratingRepository.save(userRating);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
        }
        RatingServicesImp rsi = new RatingServicesImp(ratingRepository, userRepository, movieRepository);
        userRating = rsi.createRating(user_id, movie_id, rating);
        ratingRepository.save(userRating);
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Success");
    }
}

And in my SecurityConfiguration.java file, I am trying to enable POST requests to the /movie/rate path in this way
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain2(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                authorize
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/movie/rate")
                .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // All other requests require authentication
            )
            .formLogin(formLogin ->
                formLogin
                    .loginPage("/login") // Custom login page URL
                    .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler) // Use custom success handler
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .logout(logout ->
                logout
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .clearAuthentication(true)
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
                    .permitAll()
            )
            .exceptionHandling(exception ->
                exception
                    .accessDeniedPage("/error/403") // Custom 403 error page
            );
        return http.build();
    }

I keep getting the same error when I try to submit the post request
"POST http://localhost:8080/movie/rate 404 (Not Found)"

Try disabling CSRF in SpringSeuciry Config
